# Find byte[] in PipeReader

Tags: c#

`PipeReader.ReadAsync` returns a `ReadResult` object, which in turn contains a `Buffer` property that returns a `ReadOnlySequence<byte>` object.

This data would be used to parse messages from a device, every message has a header that would be matched against the bytes in the Buffer to know where the message starts and what type to create to parse the message itself.

Problem is it doesn't seem there is any good method to do that from a `ReadOnlySequence`, and there's not much information on it around.

- It is possible to enumerate the bytes (it has a `GetEnumerator`), but after having done that I would have to manually keep track of the bytes I used to know the position in the Buffer...?
- There's also a `PositionOf` extension, but it finds the position of a single byte, so it doesn't really seem a great advantage over checking every byte in a loop.

Is there an extension method I'm missing? Is it entirely done in another way?

Comment: Out of curiosity, You mentioned "data would be used to parse messages from a device" how are you receiving that data? through socket? or some other way?

Comment: For now it's by serial port, but usually these devices support at least telnet/raw tcp too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A viable solution was to replicate the modified extensions PositionOf and PositionOfMultisegment in https://blog.joelving.dk/2018/10/reinventing-time-reporting-modern-dot-net-part-1/